# Finding support after change of variables for exponential variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I am attempting the following question:

> Suppose $X\sim\text{Expo}(1)$, $Y\sim\text{Expo}(1)$. Let $U = 6X + 8Y$
>   and $V = 2X + 3Y$. Find the joint density function of $U$ and $V$.
>   Justify whether $U$ and $V$ are independent.

My attempt so far is: if $X\sim\text{Expo}(1)$, $Y\sim\text{Expo}(1)$, then $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=e^{-(x+y)}$. Then, for U=$6X+8Y$, $V=2X+3Y$, the Jacobian is $J=\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 6 & 8 \\ 2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}=18-16=2$, so $J^{-1}=\frac12$ and $f_{UV}(u,v)=J^{-1}f_{XY}(g_1(u,v),g_2(u,v))=\frac12 e^{-\frac{u}2+v}$ (since $x=\frac{3u}2-4v$ and $y=3v-u$).

The issue now is figuring out what the support is. My understanding is that since $0<x,y<\infty$ for the exponential variables, then $0<3v-u<\infty$ and $0<\frac32 u-4v<\infty$. All I can get from this is $\frac83 v<u<3v$, and integrating $f_{UV}(u,v)$ from $\frac83 v$ to $3v$ will give $2e^{-\frac5{12}v}\cosh\frac{v}{12}$, which is assume is $f_V(v)$. However, all I can get for $u$ is $0<u<\infty$ (which seems quite fishy) and I am not sure if this is the correct approach. Could someone please clear my doubts? Thank you!

Comment: You have to mention independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is right. You can verify it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0<3v-u+and+0<3%2F2u-4v)

I would add that you don't need to calculate the marginals. The fact that the support is not a rectangle is enough to prove the dependence.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Why is it sufficient to say that it is not a rectangle? Is there a proof you could direct me to?

Comment: Because you can find a non-negligible set, in your case let's say in the neighborhood of $(u_0,v_0)=(1,2)$, for which $f_{U,V}(u,v)=0$, but $f_U(u)f_V(v)\ne 0$